# Действие при изменении значения переменной

Tags: java, javafx

Каким образом можно реализовать обработчик изменений значений переменных в JavaFX? Насколько я знаю, в JavaFX есть объекты типа SimpleIntegerProperty, и в них есть ивент, позволяющий задать действие при изменении значения. Можно ли повторить что-то подобное с базовыми int, boolean, String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать обёртку для нужного вам класса или примитивного типа и добавить список слушателей.

```java
interface MyListener {
    void execute();
}

class MyIntPropherty {
    private Integer value;
    private LinkedList<MyListener> listeners = new LinkedList<>();

    MyIntPropherty() {}

    MyIntPropherty(int i) { value = i; }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        for (MyListener listener : listeners)
            listener.execute();
    }

    public void addListener(MyListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}
```

`main`:

```java
MyIntPropherty myIntPropherty = new MyIntPropherty(10);
myIntPropherty.addListener(() -> System.out.println("Changed."));
myIntPropherty.setValue(11);
```

Вывод: `Changed.`.

При желании можно добавить разные виды ивентов и несколько списков слушателей, каждый под свой ивент.